# How to supress value of input only the first time in keydown or keyup

Tags: jquery

here I come across a little problem I do not know how I could do.

Let me explain: I have different value in the input and when I get in the values ​​I want to remove the old values

Ex : There is 90 in the input and I want that when I hit 54, 90 is supress and I can write 54. Currently I ALWAYS delete the value of my input what bothers me . So I end up with 4 ..

If someone would have an idea how to do anything like that thank you in advance!

Sincerely .

I tryed this :

```
$j(this).keydown(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            return false;
        },1000);
    $j(this).val('').change();
});
```

But the timer isn't the good answer because it get in after 1sec, and what i want is to change value to null if there's a change then don't make value to null if they keydown anything in less than 1sec.

Comment: Please provide some code, explaining what you tried already

Comment: would be great to discuss if you share the relevant code?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. Please clarify. Do you want to clear the value if the user clicks in the input and no change was made within 1 second?

Comment: Not when he click but when he write something in.
But i don't want to supress everytime he write something.
So I need to make a timer to see if he is still writing or not.

Comment: So, there is '90' in the input. I click into it and wait for a second -> the input is cleared. Then I type '15', then nothing for a second -> input stays. Is that the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solves your problem (if I understood your desired behaviour correctly)

```
var firstDown = true;
$j('#test').focus(function(){
   firstDown = true;
});
$j('#test').keydown(function() {
   if(firstDown){
       $j(this).val('');
       firstDown = false;
   }
}); 
$j('#test').blur(function(){
   firstDown = true; // not necessary
});
```

1. '90' is in the input
2. The user clicks in the input (`focus`) -> 90 stays in the input
3. The user starts to type. As soon as the first key is pressed, the input is cleared
4. The user goes on typing ('54'), and the input is not cleared anymore
5. The user clicks outside of the input (`blur`) -> the input hold '54'

**EDIT**: a more elegant (and compact) solution would be

```
$j('#test').focus(function(){
    $j(this).keydown(function() {
        $j(this).val('');
        $j(this).unbind('keydown');
    });
});
```

Comment: That seem's perfect i try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Clear it on focus rather than when you type:

```
$j(this).focus(function() {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

Now it will clear every time you click on it but won't clear everytime you type. If you try to clear on the first click then how do we know when you want to clear again and should clear it? doing it on keydown does not make that much sense.